# How to parse and split a large XML file into smaller XML files with low memory usage in Python?

Tags: python, xml, performance, memory-management, xml-parsing

I need to be able to split large XML files (anywhere from 2 to 4 million lines long) into smaller XML files which contain the same structure. I need to use python for this. The XML structure is:

```
  <queue>
        <id />
        <store_id />
        <sku />
        <url />
        <items>
          <item>
            <id></id>
            <qty></qty>
            <created_at></created_at>
            <updated_at></updated_at>
            <customer_id/>
            <external_id/>
            <data>
                <City></City>
                <State></State>
                <Firstname></Firstname>
                <Lastname></Lastname>
                .......
            </data>
            <address>
                <name></name>
                <title/>
                ........
            </address>
          </item>
          <item>
          </item>
          .......
        </items>
    </queue>
```

My current approach is to use xml.etree.ElementTree.parse() to create a large XML element, then I loop through all of the `<item>` elements inside of it, adding them to a new XML element with the same original structure.
Then once X number of items have been added, I write the new XML element to a file. After writing to a file, I replace the new XML element with a blank one and repeat this process until there are no items left.

The functionality of this is perfect. Works exactly as I want it to, however it uses a very large amount of memory. I am wondering if anyone can tell me an alternate way of achieving my goal, with less memory use.

Comment: Handle the file as plain text and iterate over it line by line.  Whenever you see a line with `<item>` or `</item>`, you know a new element has begun/ended.

Comment: @JohnGordon I thought the issue for this approach would be how slow it be. Do you suggest just writing all lines found directly to a file in plain text and not create XML element objects?

Comment: Why would it be slow?  File I/O is generally pretty fast.

Comment: You could surround each `<item>` element with fixed xml headers and footers to duplicate the structure you posted above.

Comment: So do you think I should create objects in python based off the lines read, or just keep them as strings?

Comment: Just keep them as plain strings.